# How to replace a javascript variable's value to a form field?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var battery = navigator.battery || navigator.mozBattery || navigator.webkitBattery;
</script>
<input name="battery" type="hidden" value="">
```

And I want to replace the battery's value to the input but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var battery = navigator.battery || navigator.mozBattery || navigator.webkitBattery;
</script>
<input name="battery" type="hidden" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByName("battery")[0].value = battery.level;
</script>
```

this only works if your input is the first with the name battery. If you can give it an id (the input), you can use document.getElementById("id"), wich always exactly returns one element; multiple elements with the same id are not "allowed".

Comment: document.getElementsByName("battery")[0].value = battery.level;

Comment: why do we add .level with that ?

Comment: Battery.level returns the battery level

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM functions like this :

```
var el = document.getElementById(yourId);  
el.value=battery;
```

You may use some other functions to get the element

Answer (score 1):

Put an id on the input and get/set it's value with `document.getElementById(inputId).value`

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var battery = navigator.battery || navigator.mozBattery || navigator.webkitBattery;
    document.getElementById("batt").value = battery;

    //and the other way round
    var batt = document.getElementById("batt").value;
</script>
<input id="batt" name="battery" type="hidden" value="">
```